# Как получить только используемые зависимости requirements.txt

Tags: python, django, pip, requirements.txt

Натыкался как то на пакет, которые оставляет только необходимые пакеты. Чтобы не было мусорных неиспользуемых пакетов. Никто не напомнит? Это точно не `pipreqs` так как этот решил просто выкинуть `psycopg`

Из подсказок, тот пакет, что я ищу, еще выводил в комментариях для чего используется зависимость

Comment: Предполагаю, что имели ввиду что-то типа pigar https://github.com/damnever/pigar

Comment: Да, что то похожее, но работающие с django. У меня сейчас не срабатывает, тк не может импортировать `geoip2` пакет

Comment: Тогда pip-tools? https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools

Comment: Уже больше похоже по формату вывода, но требует указания в пакетов `requirements.in`

Comment: Забавно, но ни один из вараинтов не учел `psycopg`.

Comment: Заинтересовали. Пойду крутить)))

Comment: @AndyPavlov оформите как ответ, приму,  так как оба ваших варианта решают проблему, кроме магического `psycopg2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить два варианта:

**Вариант 1**: [pigar](https://github.com/damnever/pigar). Генерирует requirements.txt как для текущей директории проекта, так и для выбранной папки. Поиск происходит на основании импортов.

Создать для рабочей директории requirements.txt

```
  pigar
```

Создать для указанной директории список зависимостей с указанным именем файла вывода

```
pigar -p ../dev-requirements.txt -P ../
```

Проверка наличия обновлений библиотек:

```
pigar -c
```

Пример вывода:

```
# stackoverflow/manage.py: 11
# stackoverflow/test/asgi.py: 12
# stackoverflow/test/urls.py: 16,17
# stackoverflow/test/wsgi.py: 12
Django == 3.2.5
```

**Вариант 2**: [pip-tools](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools) требует либо наличия `setup.py`, либо `requirements.in` для получения списка основных библиотек, для которых уже строится расширенный `requirements.txt`.

Сборка зависимостей через `setup.py`

```
pip-compile
```

Сборка зависимостей через `requirements.in`

```
pip-compile requirements.in
```

Пример вывод:

```
#
# This file is autogenerated by pip-compile
# To update, run:
#
#    pip-compile
#
asgiref==3.2.3
    # via django
django==3.0.3
    # via my_django_project (setup.py)
pytz==2019.3
    # via django
sqlparse==0.3.0
    # via django
```

Бонусом библиотека позволяет создавать слои зависимостей в виде `requirements.in`, `dev-requirements.in` для формирования зависимостей стадий рабочего проекта, разработки и т.п.

Синхронизация рабочего пространства через `pip-sync` для продакшена и, к примеру, `pip-sync requirements.txt dev-requirements.txt` для разработки.

Главный минус. Нужно формировать самому `requirements.in` и т.п.

**Для обоих библиотек** есть минус в том, что не подхватывается все, что не вызывается через `import`.