# Разделение зависимостей для локальной разработки и рабочего сервера (pip, requirements.txt)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, requirements.txt

Имеем

- Локальный проект, локальное виртуальное пространство
- Git репозиторий
- Рабочий проект (сервер), рабочее виртуальное пространство

Для создания списка зависимостей очень удобно использовать `pip freeze > requirements.txt` на локальном компьютере. Через git закинул на рабочий сервер, а далее установил все зависимости.

Но сейчас решил потестировать различные модули и в локальное виртуальное пространство установил кучу python'ских пакетов, которые обязательно попадут в `requirements.txt`, а затем в рабочее окружение. В действительности они там не нужны.

Есть ли готовое решения для управления двумя версиями зависимостей? Один для рабочего окружения, другой для локального использования. Может какой нибудь менеджер существует?

Comment: Была похожая тема недавно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1288186/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-requirements-txt/1301265#1301265

Comment: https://python-poetry.org/ может быть?

Comment: @AndyPavlov да, читал. Пробую сейчас, пробую отловить ситуации без import

Comment: virtualenv используешь?

Comment: @SergeiMalanin да, естественно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот один вариант разделения и наследования зависимостей, через включение файлов зависимостей.

Создаете файл `runtime-requirements.txt` с зависимостями для прода.

Для локальной разработки создаете `dev-requirements.txt` и туда в дополнение к зависимостям используемым чисто для разработки включаете строку:

```
-r runtime-requirements.txt
```

Она заставит pip включить все зависимости из `runtime-requirements.txt` при выполнении `pip install -r dev-requirements.txt`.

Оба файла хранятся в git, и меняются хоть вручную, хоть с помощью `pip freeze` при добавлении новых зависимостей.

Обычно я использую даже три файла: `runtime.txt` -> `test.txt` -> `dev.txt`.

`test.txt` - для использования на CI (всякие Hamcrest, testcontainers, factoryboy и прочее). `dev.txt` - `ipdb`, `django-debug-toolbar` и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно устанавливать зависимости прямо в рантайме. У меня есть [библиотечка](https://github.com/pomponchik/installed) для этого.

Устанавливается так:

```
pip install instld
```

Когда она уже установлена, можно прямо в рантайме поставить любую библиотеку:

```
import installed

with installed('some_package') as context:
  import some_module
```

Но основное удобство в том, что вы становитесь более не привязаны к конкретным сочетаниям версий библиотек. В одном рантайме могут сосуществовать две разные версии одной и той же библиотеки. Или можно параллельно использовать две несовместимые либы.

В случае использования данной библиотеки вы можете передавать ожидаемые версии зависимостей в виде переменных среды.

Answer (score 1):

Как упомянули в комментариях, можно использовать [poetry](https://python-poetry.org).

Вместо отдельных файлов зависимостей там используется общий файл проекта [`pyproject.toml`](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/), в котором могут быть отдельные разделы (группы) для обязательных зависимостей (для "боевого" окружения) и, например, для разработки. Раньше было разделение только на боевые/"разработческие" зависимости, сейчас можно создавать в принципе неограниченное количество групп.

Пример:

```bash
> poetry new test-project  # Создаем новый пустой проект
Created package test_project in test-project
> cd test-project
> ls
pyproject.toml  README.md  test_project  tests
> poetry add requests  # Добавляем "боевую зависимость"
> poetry add --group dev black # Добавляем "девелоперскую" зависимость
> poetry add --dev black # То же самое, но в стиле более старых версий poetry (напишет, что этот вариант deprecated)
> poetry add --group test pytest # Добавляем зависимость для тестирования
```

Для инициализации `pyproject.toml` в уже существующем проекте вместо `poetry new` нужно использовать `poetry init`.

Смотрим `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "test-project"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["user <user@email.com>"]
readme = "README.md"
packages = [{include = "test_project"}]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
requests = "^2.29.0"


[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
black = "^23.3.0"


[tool.poetry.group.test.dependencies]
pytest = "^7.3.1"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Локально когда вы добавили первую зависимость вам автоматом создало виртуальное окружение и установило зависимость туда.

Удаление зависимостей - через команду `poetry remove ...`. Можно править и файл `pyproject.toml`, но после изменений нужно выполнять команду `poetry update`, чтобы зависимости установились/удалились.

Дальше, если вы только выкачали проект с github, и хотите создать виртуальное окружение с установкой всех зависимостей, выполняете команду (установятся все группы зависимостей, кроме обозначенных необязательными):

```bash
poetry install
```

Если нужны только основные ("боевые") зависимости, вместо этого нужно выполнить команду

```bash
poetry install --only-root
```

Если нужно установить только основные и тестовые зависимости (но не нужны всякие форматтеры), нужна команда

```bash
poetry install --with test
```

Документация по управлению зависимостями: [Managing dependencies](https://python-poetry.org/docs/managing-dependencies/)

---

Ну и в целом как работать с poetry:

```bash
poetry run python some_script.py
```

- запустит команду в виртуальном окружении, но без постоянной активации виртуального окружения.

Это удобно, например, для запуска команд из окружения в CI:

```yaml
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        poetry run pytest --cov=./
```

Аналог активации виртуального окружения как при работе с venv/virtualenv выполняется командой

```bash
poetry shell
```

Деактивация окружения - командой `exit` (без `poetry`).