# К каким проблемам может привести отсутствие виртуального окружения для Django в PyCharm?

Tags: python, django, pycharm, virtualenv

Подскажите, какие проблемы могут быть связаны с отсутствием виртуального окружения?

Считаю, что знание об этом поможет мне в другом вопросе.

Comment: Вообще, если глобально установлено много пакетов, PyCharm будет долго их индексировать. Если же создать виртуальное окружение только с нужными пакетами, индексация будет проходить намного быстрее. Только ради этого уже стоит использовать виртуальные окружения)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавлю.

**1. Борьба с излишеством**

Во время проектирования используются только определенные модули, которые могут быть помещены в `requirements.txt`, которые соответствуют только данному проекту, для легкого переноса на тестовый сервер или на рабочий. Самая прелесть в том, что это достаточно гибкий метод для управления модулями, которые нужны именно в данный момент. Забирать из глобального окружения все модули? Зачем? [Вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303632/209304) я задавал вопрос по поводу управления `requirements.txt`. Можете обратить внимание, что используется несколько версий данного файла для каждого виртуального окружения - тестового, рабочего или еще какого

**2. Совместимость и версии**

Иметь виртуальное пространство и возможность использовать не только конкретные пакеты и модули, но и конкретные их версии отсекает множество ошибок и экономит кучу времени на их поиск. Т.е. для одного проекта хорошо работает `модуль-1.0`, при переносе на другую машину или сервер устанавливается последняя версия `модуль-2.0`. И оно не работает... Ищем ошибки, сверяем версии, тратим время. Следовательно, проще создать полностью два идентичных виртуальных окружения с идентичными модулями и их версиями.

**3. Несколько проектов на одной машине**

При данной ситуации тоже соблюдается совместимость модулей для каждого проекта и возможность использования разных версий одного модуля для каждого проекта. Не болит голова, если в одном из проектов необходимо обновить версию. Это значит, что обновление модуля для одного виртуального пространства совершенно не затронет другие. Вы можете смело эксперементировать, не боясь, что остальные проекты полетят в тартарары

Answer (score 4):

Я со своим скромным опытом вижу проблему в случае, если на этой машине разрабатывается/деплоится несколько проектов. Каждый проект привязан к своим версиям питона и библиотек. Не всегда они обратно совместимы и без багов. В результате каждое обновление и установка новой библиотеки будут касаться всех проектов на машине, а не только одного, ради которого вы что-то обновляете. Из-за бага, или того, что какой-то функционал изменили или переделали, у вас может внезапно перестать работать любой из проектов, в котором используется библиотека.